# JQuery.ajax success function returns empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, null, response

I have a very basic AJAX function in JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But the `data` is always an empty string, no matter what url I go to...  Why is that?  I am running this locally at `http://localhost:3000`, and am using JQuery 1.4.2.

If I make a local response, however, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/test",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

...it returns the html page at that address.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? (Silly, I know...)

Comment: @aviraldg How would he be able to post this question?

Comment: I don't think you can do that...

Comment: @Jacob by developing on another (offline) computer (as I do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't load data from other domains. It's a security feature.

Here's a link that talks about how to create a proxy from your web server to get around his limitation.

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 4):

You're running into the same-origin policy, preventing you from making an ajax request to another domain, for security reasons.

You **can't** make a request to:

- Another domain
- Another port, even on the same domain
- A sibling domain

You **can** make a request to:

- The same domain
- A subdomain of the current domain

[You can read more about it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: thanks! how then are these people making/using [JQuery RSS readers like this one](http://www.hovinne.com/blog/index.php/2007/07/15/132-jfeed-jquery-rss-atom-feed-parser-plugin)?

Comment: [got it](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/cross-domain-rss-to-json-converter.html)

Comment: Something is not logical: why in that case is not an error, but a success with an empty answer?